# terraform network_interface_ids - Inappropriate value for attribute

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to set the "network_interface_ids" within "azurerm_virtual_machine" to the output of one of my modules, but am receiving the following error during the "terraform plan" and can't figure out where I'm going wrong:

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on modules/virtualmachine/main.tf line 6, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm":
│    6:   network_interface_ids             = [var.nicid]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.nicid is a list of string, known only after apply
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_ids": element 0:
│ string required.
╵
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

I'm sure this is something simple, I have it working without being split out into modules just can't quite figure it out. I've attached all of the relevant code below (obviously removed the bulk of the code to help with brevity):

main.tf

```
  module "virtualmachine" {
  source                   = "./modules/virtualmachine"
  nicid                    = module.networking.nicidoutput
  }
```

modules/networking/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = var.nicname
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}
```

modules/networking/outputs.tf

```
output "nicidoutput" {
    value = azurerm_network_interface.nic.id
}
```

modules/virtualmachine/main.tf

```
  resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  network_interface_ids             = [var.nicid]
  }
```

modules/virtualmachine/variables.tf

```
variable "nicid" {
    type = list(string)
    description = "network interface id"
}
```

Comment: Is the `networking` module invoked anywhere?

Comment: Yep, I'm using other resources within the networking module without any errors

Comment: Would you mind adding that block as-is to the question?

Comment: @MarkoE thank you for your assistance! However, the accepted answer below was the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `var.nicid` is already a list. So it should be:

```
network_interface_ids             = var.nicid
```

update:

also the following should be changed in `virtualmachine`

```
nicid                    = [module.networking.nicidoutput] for virtualmachine
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when I make that change I get the following error:

 `Error: Invalid value for module argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 75, in module "virtualmachine":
│   75:   nicid                    = module.networking.nicidoutput
│ 
│ The given value is not suitable for child module variable "nicid" defined
│ at modules/virtualmachine/variables.tf:33,1-17: list of string required.
╵
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.`

Comment: @vegedezozu You can try with `nicid                    = [module.networking.nicidoutput]` for `virtualmachine`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I knew it was something simple. Rather frustrating >_<. But thanks again!

Comment: of course, did you want to add in the comment above to the answer so it's all in one place?